# System namespaces missing MonoDevelop on fresh install

Tags: mono, ide, monodevelop, c#

I am wondering if anyone can help me, I did a fresh install of MonoDevelop on a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS with .NET Core 2.2 installed (everything updated), then followed the instructions layed out at [Mono Download Offical](https://www.monodevelop.com/download/). I have no errors or warnings during installation.

When I create any type of project or open one, all the system namespaces are missing?

[image: Missing namespaces]

I have checked here:

[image]

And

[image: Runtimes]

When I build / Clean any project I get:

```
/home/ant/.cache/MonoDevelop/7.0/MSBuild/27259_1/Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets(5,5): Error MSB4019:   
  The imported project "/home/ant/.cache/MonoDevelop/7.0/MSBuild/27259_1//Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets" was not found.   
  Confirm that the path in the declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk. (MSB4019) (sadsad)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Monodevelop under Raspian (Rasberry3)
I believe I can now offer a viable solution:
(for Monodevelop, Raspian, Raspberry 3)

It's just a setting that has to be done in Monodevelop before you start a new project:

Search under the settings, create and disable the line "create with MSBuild instead of xbuild".

After that all new projects will be recognized without errors.

For old projects the procedure is similar:
but there you should delete the folder ".vs" in the project folder first (better make a backup copy first! ;) ) 
Start Monodevelop. Check that the settings are as described above. 
Then open the project in Monodelop.
When you open the project, it will be reinitialized and can then be edited and compiled without any problems.